# ironxl's range method Copy() destroys excel styles while copying row

Tags: c#, excel

Im using ironXL library to build excel reports. When im trying to copy row with Range class method Copy(), im getting corrupted excel that has no styling.
Here is how im copying row:
`var rowToCopy = workbook.WorkSheets[0].Rows[8];`

`rowToCopy.Copy(workbook.WorkSheets[0], "A20");`

If anyone here knows how to fix it - please share your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Corrupted excel that has no styling.

I have only had this issue with IronXL when loading an XSL file but saving it as XLSX or vice versa.  I wonder if your issue is similar.